# как переместить минимальный объект после максимального в структуре?

Tags: c++, указатели, список, структуры

У меня дан односвязный список, в нем мне нужно найти минимальный и максимальный элементы и поместить минимальный после максимального. Я получил такие элементы:

```
//Макс
Single_List max = Find_Max_Elem(Head);//Нашёл максимум
Single_List *postMax = (&max)->Next;//следующий элемент максимума
//Мин
Single_List preMin = Find_PreMin_Elem(Head);//элем, перед минимумом
Single_List *min=(&preMin)->Next;//минимум
Single_List *postMin = min->Next;//максимум
```

Как я понял, мне для начала нужно от (соседа слева) от минимума сослаться на (соседа справа). При выводе мы не должны увидеть минимального элемента, а у меня все так и не меняется. В чём ошибка?

```
(&preMin)->Next = postMin;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что работаете ни с указателем на минимальный элемент, а с его копией. В вашем предыдущем вопросе, в результате одной из правок, я все таки поправил прототип, в котором оказалась ошибка при копировании. В теории, ваш код по переносу элемента должен выглядеть так:

```
Single_List* max(Find_Max_Elem(Head)); // Обратите внимание, здесь тоже должен быть указатель, чтобы работать именно с элементом списка, а не с его копией
Single_List* preMin(Find_PreMin_Elem(Head));
Single_List* min(preMin->Next);
preMin->Next = min->Next;
min->Next = max->Next;
max->Next = min;
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, выручил! :)